# Как суммируется вложенный список?

Tags: python, индексация

Положим, у нас есть список списков, где верхний список - список по годам, и в каждом годе список по месяцам.

```
data = [
[43.8, 60.5, 190.2, ],
[49.9, 54.3, 109.7, ],
[63.7, 72.0, 142.3, ],

]
```

считаем среднее по месяцам:

```
monthly_mean = []
n = len(data) # no of years
for m in range(12): 
    s = 0 # sum
    for y in data: 
        s += y[m] 
    monthly_mean.append(s/n)
```

единственное, у нас же при присвоении идёт первый, т.е. верхний, индекс списка "дата", т.е. года. Мы не должны таким кодом выбрать первые 12 лет (in range (12))? Почему не выбран нижний список?

Comment: ваш код работает правильно. если вам нужно среднее за январь по всем годам и так далее...

Answer (score 3):

*Не уверен что ответ соотвествует вопросу, но автору для анализа возможно понадобится.*

- `считаем среднее по месяцам:`
- `Почему не выбран нижний список?`

*Эти два пункта в вопросе, не дают окончательно определиться что имеенно подразумевалось (но у меня и считается среднее по месяцам, не годам, и учитывается последняя строка - нижний список)*

**Ответ:**

На всякий случай я доработал функцию в случае если год не полный

- `d` = это дельта (т.е. отнимаемое значение от высоты столбика - количества лет)
- `len(y) > m` - если в году есть этот месяц

  ```
  import numpy as np

  data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    [1, 2, 30,],
  ]

  monthly_mean = []
  for m in range(12): 
    s = 0
    d = 1 if len(data[ len(data) - 1]) <= m else 0
    n = len(data) - d 
    for y in data: 
      if (len(y) > m):
         s += y[m] 
    monthly_mean.append(s / n)


  print(monthly_mean)
  ```

  [1.0, 2.0, 8.4, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0]

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятна суть вопроса, но если задача стоит посчитать среднегодовые значения, то:

```
monthly_mean = []
for year in data:
    #  Если в каждом году данные всегда за полный год
    s = sum(year)/12
    #  Если же возможно, что за какой-то год неполное кол-во месяцев
    s = sum(year)/len(year)
    monthly_mean.append(s)
```

Или еще проще:

```
monthly_mean = [sum(year)/len(year) for year in data]
```

На выходе для приведенного списка data получим:
`[64.06666666666666, 71.3, 92.66666666666667]`

> пособие утверждает, что тем кодом машина считывает месяца, т.е. нижний
> уровень. код же очевидно вызывает верхний.

UPD: Прошу прощения за невнимательность. Только сейчас догнал суть.

```
monthly_mean = []
n = len(data) # количество
for m in range(12): # m - это порядковый номер месяца в году
    s = 0 # sum
    for y in data: # y = это массив "год", проходим по всем годам
        s += y[m]  # и суммируем показатели за месяц m
    monthly_mean.append(s/n) # добавляем в массив
```

Таким образом, в пособии написано верно.
Считываем и суммируем сначала данные за 1 месяц каждого года, и делим
на количество лет. Потом за второй месяц и так далее, до 12 месяца.

Comment: главная суть: почему индексом y[m] выбран нижний список? у нас список списков: [[месяц, месяц], [месяц, месяц], [месяц, месяц]]. разве не должны мы по [x] выбрать каждый список в ВЕРХНЕМ списке. а выбран нижний

Comment: Это зависит от задачи. Если надо посчитать среднее за каждый год, как в моем примере, то да. А если например надо знать за несколько лет средние значения января, февраля, марта и т.д. - это делает ваш код. Только смущает `for m in range(12):`, это подразумевает, что в data должны быть данные не менее, чем за 12 лет, а если там будет больше лет, то посчитается все равно только за 12.

Comment: именно! лет. а это не года, а месяца! пособие утверждает, что тем кодом машина считывает месяца, т.е. нижний уровень. код же очевидно вызывает верхний. собственно, вопрос только в этом